# Regex to match values of hundreds and thousands in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex

I am trying to find a working regular expression which allows me to find all prices of a web page which are like `1,150.00` and `500.00`

This regular expression works for me in Rubular:

```
/(\d?,?\d+.\d+)/
```

But it doesn't work in my Ruby code, as it is ok for values in the hundreds, but takes only the first number in the thousands (takes the 1 in 1,150.00, for example).

Is there something I'm missing?

This is the code I'm using:

```
str_rooms_prices = rooms_container.scan(/[\d,]?\d+\.\d+\s/)

puts "This is the room prices I've found so far #{str_rooms_prices}."

str_rooms_prices = str_rooms_prices - ["0"]

puts "I'm now substracting the 0 prices and this is what remains: #{str_rooms_prices}."

int_rooms_prices = str_rooms_prices.map { |str| str.to_i }

min_price = int_rooms_prices.min.to_i
```

And then the min_price I get is 1.

Comment: Where are your captures? Any reason you wouldn't use something like `/(\d[,\d]*(\.\d{2)?)/`

Comment: You should show us the Ruby code you're using to match.  A http://SSCCE.org.

Comment: Your regex is not giving me the results I expected. Look, here is an improved version of my regex, it works on Rubular, but again it doesn't in Ruby: http://rubular.com/r/jfjFfSnd4Z

Comment: Sure Frankie, I just updated the question with my code

Comment: Samer, your regex is returning stuff you DONT want..  namely: match 11, 17, and 18

Comment: True! I hadn't noticed it :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting `min_price` 1 because of your conversion `to_i`.

```
'1,150.00'.to_i
=> 1
```

Try the following:

```
int_rooms_prices = str_rooms_prices.map { |str| str[0].tr(',','').to_i }
```

Important to note that you should be converting the prices to units, otherwise the decimal places will be lost. So convert the values to units using `to_f`, then multiply by 100 to get the full value and then you can convert to an integer.

```
int_rooms_prices = str_rooms_prices.map { |str| (str[0].tr(',','').to_f*100).to_i }
```

Then you can use [number_to_currency](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/NumberHelper.html#method-i-number_to_currency) to display the correct price, like so:

```
number_to_currency(min_price/100)
```

Comment: That did the trick! Seems I need to learn more Ruby rather than regex :P

Comment: Note that you use `to_i` (to integer) although matching the decimal places. These will be truncated unless you use `to_f` (to float).

Comment: You're absolutely right @padde, the values shouldn't have any decimal places. Updated my answer accordingly. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

I think your regex is overly complex. In my opinion `/[\d,.]+/` will do just fine. Also, you are using `to_i` which will break because of the commas

```
'1,000,000.00'.to_i
#=> 1
```

so you need to remove those commas first, for example with `String#delete`

```
'1,000,000.00'.delete(',').to_i
#=> 1000000
```

Another problem with `to_i` is, that it will discard decimal places because it converts the number to an integer:

```
'1.23'.to_i
#=> 1
```

so you should use `to_f` instead:

```
'1.23'.to_f
#=> 1.23
```

Here's a complete example that even handles negative values:

```
str = "Subtracting 1,500.00 from 1,150.23 leaves you with -350.77"
str.scan(/-?[\d,.]+/).map{|s| s.delete(',').to_f }
#=> [1500.0, 1150.23, -350.77]
```

If you really don't need the decimal places, use `to_i` of course.

Comment: +1. Nice and concise regex, the way they should be, and good explanation.